# extract real number from array in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, complex-numbers

I would like to extract only the real numbers from an array containing imaginary numbers also
I would like to eliminate the imaginary numbers from array. Therefore, from an array of 10 elements, of which 5 real, and 5 imaginary, to obtain an array of only 5 elements, which must be the real numbers element. This in MATLAB

**EDIT:**

Adding an example

```
input_array = [ 1, 1+i, -2+2*j, 3, -4, j ];
```

The desired output would be

```
output = [ 1, 3, -4 ];
```

which contains only real elements of `input_array`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another, more vectorized way:

```
sel = a == real(a); % choose only real elements

only_reals = a( sel );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you can enjoy good health up to 150 years!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [isreal](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/isreal.html) in combination with [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to check if numbers are real and/or  [real](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/real.html) to just keep the real parts. Examples:

```
a = [1+i 2 3 -1-i];
realidx = arrayfun(@isreal,a);
only_reals = a(realidx);
only_real_part = real(a);

>> only_reals

  = [ 2  3]

>> only_real_part

  = [1 2 3 -1]
```

Comment: +1 I always forget about arrayfun.

Comment: basically it's also a loop, but it's nice for one-liners

Comment: @GuntherStruyf Hopefully in future releases all the `*fun` functions will be efficiently implemented (parallel or something...)

Comment: realidx is always zero and only_reals is empty

Comment: @carminePat not here, what did you put into `a`?

Comment: I also only get 0 when applying `isreal` with `arrayfun`.

Answer (score 4):

Real numbers have an imaginary part of zero, so:

```
input_array(imag(input_array)==0);

ans =
    1     3    -4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [`isreal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isreal.html) function. Turns out `isreal` does not give a vector output, which is weird for MATLAB, since it usually does. So, you need to use a for loop.

```
arr = [1+i 5 6-3i 8];
arrReal = [];
for idx = 1:numel(arr)
    if isreal(arr(idx))
        arrReal(end+1) = arr(idx);
    end
end
```

I suppose great folks here will come up with a loopless solution.

Shai's edit:

A version with pre-allocation of output result

```
arrReal = NaN( size(arr) ); % pre-allocation
for idx = 1:numel(arr)
    if isreal( arr(idx) )
        arrReal(idx) = arr(idx);
    end
end
arrReal( isnan( arrReal ) ) = []; % discard non-relevant entries
```

Of course, this goal can be achieved without loops (see other answers). But for this loopy version, a pre-allocation is a significant ingredient.

Comment: an interesting use of `isreal`. However your answer has two major drawbacks: 1. it uses a loop (as you have already noted). 2. the output `arrReal` grows inside the loop. This type of memory usage causes Matlab to **really** slow down. A better way is to pre-allocate `arrReal` to the size of `arr` and remove the redundant part after the loop.  

Anyhow, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Shai I thought about preallocation but could not come up with a way to index `arrReal` other than keeping another index variable. So, I decided not to. But I probably should have anyway. Do you know a more clever way?

Comment: I just edited your answer and added a version with pre-allocation. Hope you like it.

Comment: @Shai your edit had been rejected when I saw it. So, I copied your solution.